# How to style a Google Workspace Marketplace Addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, add-on, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have checked the documentation of Google Workspace Marketplace add-ons and I have not been able to find out how to change the styles of its cards and components (e.g. Header, Footer, Buttons, Paddings, Margins, Fonts, etc.). I just want to know if there's a solution to this or any document that would guide me in the right direction and if it is actually possible to do so?

**Title**

[image: Title of the Add-On]

**Button**

[image: Button of the Add-On]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since Google Workspace add-ons make use of cards, there's no way to style them directly as you would normally do with the editor add-ons.**

However, according to the official documentation, you might benefit from trying the Google Workspace add-ons UI [design kit](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/introducing-easier-way-to-design-your-gsuite-add-on.html) available on Figma.

#### Reference

- [UI style guide for Google Workspace add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/gsuite-style);
- [Design kit guide](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/introducing-easier-way-to-design-your-gsuite-add-on.html).

Comment: Thank you ale. I already saw the design kit but the reviews were pretty bad. I'll still try it out to test it for myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Styling options of Google Workspace Add-ons are very limited.

There are a few things that you can tune:

1. Set-up primaryColor and secondaryColor in deployment configuration
2. Change color of buttons by specifying color option
3. Change the color, style (bold, italics) of any text inside the widget